# Why does un-jar then jar again break my Spring Boot web app?

Tags: spring-boot, jar, unjar

I built a Spring Boot web app (using Eclipse/STS) that has an embedded tomcat server.

I need to do some (obfuscation) stuff to classes inside the WAR file and the zip it back up again, but before I try that I'm unzipping and then zipping up again to make sure that will work.

But when I unzip it then zip it back up it won't run anymore ...

Steps to reproduce:

1. Run the application like so ... `java -jar myapp.war` ... it works fine.  Kill the application.
2. "Un-zip" the war like so ... `jar -xf myapp.war` ... all the contents are extracted.
3. Delete the original war file ... `rm myapp.war`
4. "Re-zip" the contents into a war like so ... `jar -cfv myapp.war .`
5. Run the new war file ... `java -jar myapp.war` ... I get an error ...

`no main manifest attribute, in myapp.war`

When I extract the contents of the new war file, I see that my original /META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file has been replaced by:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.7.0_06 (Oracle Corporation)
```

I'm probably doing something wrong on step (4) above.  Any ideas?  Is there a "Spring Boot"-specific thing I'm suppose to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I figured it out ... I have to use the `m` option and specify the manifest file like this ...

```
jar -cfm myapp.war ./META-INF/MANIFEST.MF .
```

I had incorrectly assumed it would just include the existing manifest file from that directory.